# Local parallel computations for a summing operation

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, openmp, cython

I've started messing around with parallel programming and cython/openmp, and I have a simple program that sums over an array using prange:

```
import numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange
from cython import boundscheck, wraparound

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)

def parallel_summation(double[:] vec):

    cdef int n = vec.shape[0]
    cdef double total
    cdef int i

    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
        total += vec[i]

    return total
```

It seems to work OK with a setup.py file. However, I was wondering if it is possible to adjust this function and have a little more control over what the processors are doing.

Let's say I have 4 processors: I want to split the vector to be summed into 4 parts, and then have each processor locally add the elements inside. Then at the end, I can combine the results from each processor to get the total sum. From the cython documentation, I wasn't able to gather whether something like this is possible or not (the documentation is a little sparse).

I'd appreciate if someone could explain if/how something like this is done using cython/openmp, or maybe help locate some relevant examples (its been surprisingly hard to find simple ones online).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to split the vector to be summed into 4 parts, and then have each processor locally add the elements inside. Then at the end, I can combine the results from each processor to get the total sum.

That's exactly what's happening here already. Cython infers from your inplace operation that you want to do a reduction. OpenMP will implement a parallel loop with private (zero initialized) copies of the `total` variable and add them all to `total` at the end of the loop.

In the generated C, this looks like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for firstprivate(__pyx_v_i) lastprivate(__pyx_v_i) reduction(+:__pyx_v_total)
    for (__pyx_t_2 = 0; __pyx_t_2 < __pyx_t_3; __pyx_t_2++){
        {
            __pyx_v_i = (int)(0 + 1 * __pyx_t_2);
            __pyx_t_4 = __pyx_v_i;
            __pyx_v_total = (__pyx_v_total + (*((double *) ( /* dim=0 */ (__pyx_v_vec.data + __pyx_t_4 * __pyx_v_vec.strides[0]) ))));
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to enable OpenMP [as described here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html#compiling).

The one thing that you should change in your code, is to initialize `total = 0`, otherwise it's just an unitialized C variable with may contain garbage.